# How to fix the wrong frame after device rotation?

Tags: swift, uiview, swift4, device-orientation

I use custom alert view in my application. When called, its frame completely fills the screen. However, after the device rotates, it does not look right.

[image: look right]
[image: look wrong]

Then I try to change my alert frame and assign it a new screen size in `viewWillTransition`

```
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true) }
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        if let _ = alert {
            alert?.rotateAlert(to: size)
            Logger.Log("after size = \(alert?.backgroundView.frame.size)")
            Logger.Log("after frame = \(alert?.frame)")
            Logger.Log("after bounds = \(alert?.bounds)")
        }
```

I tried to do the same in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if let _ = alert {
            Logger.Log("viewDidLayoutSubviews before rotation")
            alert?.rotateAlert(to: self.view.frame.size)
            Logger.Log("after size = \(alert?.backgroundView.frame.size)")
            Logger.Log("after frame = \(alert?.frame)")
            Logger.Log("after bounds = \(alert?.bounds)")
        }
    }
```

```
    func rotateAlert(to size: CGSize) {
        self.frame.size = size
        backgroundView.frame = frame
    }
```

Thus the frame of my alert changes. But its size is still smaller than the screen in height, thus forming an empty area.

[image]

Why is this happening? And how do I fix this? (I use Swift4)

Comment: Use constraints instead of dealing with frame changes.

Answer (score 0):

To place your `alert` in the center of the screen, assuming that it is an instance of `UIView`, do this:

```swift
alert.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
alert.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

// Or 
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  alert.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
  alert.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
])
```

This is using auto layout to position your views, and the views will properly update when the trait collection changes.

Comment: but its new size is smaller than the screen size. Moving it to the center will not solve this problem.

Comment: @AlexKirov If you have a fixed frame size, you can also make constraints to its width and height: alert.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true and do the same for the heightAnchor.

Comment: Where is the alert added to as a subview?

Comment: Also, make sure you remove all code that relates to manually rotating the alert, e.g. the one in your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

Comment: @famfamfam  Did you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`?

Comment: the problem is the rounder corner topleft/topright in viewDidLoad, i moved to viewWillLayoutSubviews then now it work normally, but i still do not know the problem

Answer (score 0):

When adding a view programmatically the view doesn't adjust according to the screen rotation because you have fixed the view height, width so after rotation you need to again give its frame.

This doesn't happen when you **use constraints** to add a view either programmatically or from the storyboard

For your alert to resize you have to again give its frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    YourAlertView.frame = CGRect(x:0 , y: 0,width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height )
}
```

Works like a charm for me.